# Difficult button to press in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

how to press the "f_agreements_all" button ?

```
<label for="f_agreements_all">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="f_agreements_all">
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="permText">I accept all</span>
                </label>
```

Unfortunately, finding "f_agreements_all" button and clicking it doesnt work. Span covers the whole button17x17px, when f_agreements_all is 16x16 under it. Do you know possible way to click it?[image]

Comment: maybe use javascript to click it.

Comment: can you tell me how ? i only know how to use python, not javascript

Comment: selenium has `driver.execute_script("some javascript code")`

Comment: I added an approach below but I would edit your question to state how you are finding the button and clicking it and what other methods you tried. Also add what Selenium version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below xpath :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


button=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='formCheckbox agreements all-agreements']//span[1]")))
button.click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this error occures     raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Can you share your url? if not then please check if element is in iframe

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla JS one way to do it would be:

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById('f_agreements_all');
checkbox.click();
```

Quickly looking at the [Python Selenium 2 WebDriver API](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) docs, one can try:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("f_agreements_all").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='f_agreements_all']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='f_agreements_all']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```